# How to fix the Error "TypeError: cy.[custom command] is not a function"?

Tags: javascript, typescript, cypress

I have written some function in commands.js file for cypress automation testing, out of which I am able to invoke only one i.e."login" but unable to invoke other functions form another .js file. Cypress Test Runner showing

> "TypeError: `cy.FillAddCaseDetails` is not a function"

```js
describe('Adding a Case on CSS Poratal ', function() {

  before(function () {
    cy.login()    // calling login function successfully
  })

  it('open add case',function(){
    cy.wait(9000)
    cy.hash().should('contains','#/home')
    cy.wait(['@GETcontentLoad']);
    cy.wait(['@POSTcontentLoad']);
    cy.get('[uib-tooltip="Add Case"]').click({force:true})
    cy.log('clicked on Add case')
    cy.wait(3000) 
    cy.get('[ng-click="lookup.cancel()"]').click({force: true})
    cy.get('[ng-click="lookup.closeAddCase()"]').click({force: true})
    cy.get('[uib-tooltip="Add Case"]').click({force:true}) 
    cy.wait(3000)
    cy.get('[ng-model="lookup.selectedPartner"]',{force:true})
      .type(AddJob.JobData.Partner,{force: true}) 
    cy.xpath('//input[@ng-model="lookup.selectedPartner"]')
      .should('be.visible').then(() => {
        cy.FillAddCaseDetails()   // unable to call   
        cy.FillCustomerDetails()  // unable to call 
      })
```

Function:

```js
Cypress.Commands.add("FillCustomerDetails", () => {

  cy.get('[ng-model="lookup.firstName"]')
    .type(AddJob.JobData.FirstName, { force: true}) 

  cy.get('[ng-model="lookup.lastName"]')
    .type(AddJob.JobData.LastName, { force: true })

  cy.get('[ng-model="lookup.customerPhone"]')
    .type(AddJob.JobData.CustomerPhone, { force: true })

  cy.get('[value="NEXT"]').click({ force: true })
})
```

expected : function will get called

actual : TypeError: `cy.FillAddCaseDetails` is not a function

Comment: You can [edit] your question, please don't post code in comments

Answer (score 11):

This is the top result for this error so I would like to add what I did to fix it.  This is relevant to version >=10 and typescript.  The problem ended up being that the `supportFile` setting in `cypress.config.ts` was set to `false`;  I changed my config to this:

```
import cypress, { defineConfig } from 'cypress'

export default defineConfig({
  
  e2e: {
    'baseUrl': 'http://localhost:4200',
    supportFile: 'cypress/support/e2e.ts'
  },
  
  
})
```

I created the custom commands in `commands.ts`

```
declare namespace Cypress {
  interface Chainable<Subject = any> {
    /**
     * Custom command to select DOM element by data-cy attribute.
     * @example cy.dataCy('greeting')
    */
     clearIndexedDB(): Promise<void>
  }
}

Cypress.Commands.add('clearIndexedDB', async () => {
  const databases = await window.indexedDB.databases();

  await Promise.all(
    databases.map(
      ({ name }) => {
        if (!name) return
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          const request = window.indexedDB.deleteDatabase(name);

          request.addEventListener('success', resolve);
          request.addEventListener('blocked', resolve);
          request.addEventListener('error', reject);
        })
      },
    ),
  );
});
```

Then I uncommented this line in my e2e.ts file

```
import './commands';
```

Comment: I removed the `supportFile: false` line,  and it worked

Answer (score 2):

If you added your Custom Command to `support/commands.js` file, You need to import that file from `support/index.js` file. Create `support/index.js`, if it's not available and add the line `import "./commands.js"` to it.

Comment: This did not work for me.

Answer (score 1):

In my case solution was a restart of the cypress test runner.

Answer (score -2):

From the Cypress docs: https://on.cypress.io/typescript#Types-for-custom-commands

if you add the command cy.dataCy into your supportFile like this:

```js
// cypress/support/index.js
Cypress.Commands.add('dataCy', (value) => {
  return cy.get(`[data-cy=${value}]`)
})
```

Then you can add the dataCy command to the global Cypress Chainable interface (so called because commands are chained together) by creating a new TypeScript definitions file beside your supportFile, in this case at cypress/support/index.d.ts.

```
// in cypress/support/index.d.ts
// load type definitions that come with Cypress module
/// <reference types="cypress" />

declare namespace Cypress {
  interface Chainable {
    /**
     * Custom command to select DOM element by data-cy attribute.
     * @example cy.dataCy('greeting')
    */
    dataCy(value: string): Chainable<Element>
  }
}
```

Answer (score -6):

cy.xpath("//div[@class='c-navigatorItem-faceplate ng-scope ng-isolate-scope']").click();
Is it a valid to use because I am getting the TypeError cy.xpath is not a function

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! Before asking, make sure to read our article: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Make sure to use the `Answer` field to Answers, and the `Comment` field to comments. Hope it helps!