# Cypress 10 : How to define custom command as global and use in seperate test files

Tags: angular, cypress

I'm trying to implement some custom commands in Cypress 10.3 that can be used as global in different test cases or in other words in different files.

I created a functions.ts file in the support folder and defined a custom command there and have been imported it into the e2e.ts file But when I want to use the function in another file, I get an error saying `cy.getBody is not a function`

I also tried to define the function into interface but I'dont know how can I to implement the function to be used as a global command.

**cypress/support/commands.ts**:

```
declare global {
  namespace Cypress {
    interface Chainable {
     
      getBody() : Chainable<Element>

    }
  }  
}

Cypress.Commands.add('getBody', () => {return 'some text ...'})
```

here is **tsconfig.json**

```
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "lib": ["es6", "dom"],
    "types": ["cypress", "cypress-file-upload"],
    "rootDir": "./",
    "moduleResolution": "node"
  },
  "include": ["**/*.ts"]
}
```

Comment: side note: do not forget to import that `functions.ts` file in the `support/index`. After that, IMO, we do not have to do import for the custom commands. Always available as `cy.customCommandName()`

Comment: @KiranParajuli There is no more index file in Cypress version 10.x. it is replaced by e2e.ts

Comment: Sorry :) Didn't know that. Cypress is getting updated so fast. 

Answer (score 0):

As long as you import `functions.ts` into `cypress/support/e2e.ts`, you should have the commands available in every test.

The type declaration has the wrong return type however,

**cypress/support/functions.ts**

```
/// <reference types="cypress" />

declare global {
  namespace Cypress {
    interface Chainable {
      getBody() : Chainable<string>   // you are returning 'some text ...'
    }
  }  
}

Cypress.Commands.add('getBody', () => {
  return cy.wrap('some text ...')
})

export default {}  // syntactic sugar - makes this a module
```

**cypress/support/e2e.ts**

```js
import './commands'
import './functions'

...
```

Comment: I get the error >TypeError : cy.getBody is not a function

Comment: the command is available in every test, but if I run the test, I get the error >TypeError : cy.getBody is not a function

Comment: Above have added a version that works for me. If you return a primitive (e.g string) wrap it first. Also added a module default export to avoid grumbling about `global`.

Comment: I copied your code and pasted it into functions.ts but I still get the same error.
Cypress version : 10.3.1

Comment: Let me compare the tsconfig.json - it's the only other thing I can think needs adjusting.

Comment: Above in the post I added the tsconfig.json.

Comment: So I pasted your tsconfig into my system and am still ok. Normally I have two tsconfig, one at project root and one in /cypress folder. I removed the cypress one and just used the root one, which I presume is where you have it. Sorry, but I can't make it break.

Comment: @vsam - Did you find working solution for this ? I am not able to access the custom command in support/e2e.js file. Though I am able to access command from my spec file.

Comment: @BhavarthKandoria actually no. so far I haven't found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and as mentioned in this answer:
[Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57888484/how-to-fix-the-error-typeerror-cy-custom-command-is-not-a-function/74380477#74380477)

the problem was that I had:

```
supportFile: false
```

in my cypress.config.ts file

I just removed this line and everything works fine.

Comment: That would cause a different error - turning off the support file means the custom command would not be visible at all.